# How to redirect other URL in Symfony3 with parameter

Tags: php, symfony-forms, symfony

I have trouble how to redirect other URL with parameter. In the following code, it shows the error message when $resultFlg is equal to True.

The message states that 'Unable to generate a URL for the named route "snsForm" as such route does not exist'. I don't understand the reason and the solution. Please use routing.yml as a reference. Then, Symfony version is 3.0.4-DEV.

src/AppBundle/Controller/UserController.php

```
/**
 * @Route("/form", name="userForm")
 */
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
     ........
     $resultFlg = $this->existedUserCheck($userId, $password);

     if($resultFlg){
     // failed
         return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('snsForm'));

     }else{
         $loginResultMessage = 'No registered User Id: ' . $userId;

     }
     .......
}

/**
 * @Route("/snsForm", name="regsiterSnsRoute")
 */
public function registerSnsInfoAction(Request $request)
{
    .......
}
```

app/config/routing.yml

```
app:
resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
type:     annotation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to direct to the name of the route not the url.  In your case it is 'regsiterSnsRoute'

```
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('regsiterSnsRoute'));
```

also you can shorten that line to

```
return $this->redirectToRoute('regsiterSnsRoute');
```

Comment: Thanks to your answer, redirect function worked properly. I thought I had to input URL path because method name was generateUrl.